# Localazy: Localazy Gradle plugin requires Android Gradle plugin 3.5.0 and newer

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gradle, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to use https://localazy.com/p/locakalazy/integration/android for android language localization.

But while adding this in app module ->

```
apply plugin: 'com.localazy.gradle'

localazy {
    readKey "########"
    writeKey "########"
}
```

I am getting this error ->

Build file 'C:\Users\91863\AndroidStudioProjects\android-localization\app\build.gradle' line: 48

An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.localazy.gradle']

**Failed to apply plugin 'com.localazy.gradle'.
Localazy: Localazy Gradle plugin requires Android Gradle plugin 3.5.0 and newer.**

But I do have the newer plugin version
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of the Localazy Gradle plugin and I will do my best to help you resolve the issue.

It seems that the version cannot be obtained correctly from the Android Gradle plugin and thus Localazy Gradle plugin fails.

Would you be so kind to contact us through the online chat on our website? I would need more information about your situation to simulate and resolve it.

Once we fix it for you (and possibly all other users as well), I will publish the solution here.

---

**EDIT: The detection mechanism was fixed in version 1.5.4.**